# Java socket cannot properly display the input received

Tags: java, python, sockets, network-programming, java.util.scanner

I am trying to get a Java client side program to receive input from the server. However the code cannot get the input and print it out. It compiled fine.
The problem is that the received input is not printed out to the console.
Here is the part which creates the socket

```
Socket ss = new Socket(host,port);
String input;
Scanner in;
in = new Scanner(ss.getInputStream());
while(true)
{
    input = in.next();
    System.out.print(input + "\n");
    if("quit".equalsIgnoreCase(input));
        {
            in.close();
            ss.close();
            return;
        }
}
```

Here is all of my code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class connect 
{
    static int port;
    static String host;
    public static void start(String host, int port)
    {
        while(true)
        {
        try 
        {
            Socket ss = new Socket(host,port);
            String input;
            Scanner in;
            in = new Scanner(ss.getInputStream());
            while(true)
            {
                input = in.next();
                System.out.print(input + "\n");
                if("quit".equalsIgnoreCase(input));
                {
                    in.close();
                    ss.close();
                    return;
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String check;
        do
        {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Hello, welcome to the client");
        String banner = "-";
        int x = 0;

        while(x<60)
        {
            banner += "-";
            x++;
        }
        System.out.println(banner);
        System.out.print("\n\nPlease Enter the ip address to connect to\n>>");
        host = sc.next();
        System.out.println("We are connecting to " + host);
        System.out.print("\n" + banner + "\nEnter the port\n>>");
        port = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Connecting to\nhost->" + host + "\nport->" + port);
        System.out.println("Enter 'Done' to continue, any to reset");
        check = sc.next();
        }while(!"Done".equals(check));
        start(host,port);
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }
}
```

The server was made with python, just to test it out. Here is the python code

```
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('',443))
s.listen(1)
conn,addr=s.accept()
conn.send("Hello")
conn.send("World")
```

The ouput of this code in the client side should be

-->Hello

-->World

Hello should be printed then World should be printed then wait for more input. However the output is not displayed until the server is closed. When the server is closed it displays HelloWorld

Comment: You should add a space after each word,. ex: `... conn.send("Hello") conn.send(" ")
conn.send("World") ...`

Comment: That would fix the whitespace issue, but not the fact that the input is not displaced

Comment: The scanner class is waiting for a token (by default its a whitespace delimited chunk of text) so you need to send `"Hello Word "` (note the ending space) if you want those tokens. Read up on [java's Scanner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: It works when you exit the server because that terminates the connection and the scanner sees EOF. it would also work if you did `conn.shutdown(socket.SOCK_RDWR)` but then the connection would be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the python documentation for [send](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send):

> Applications are responsible for checking that all data has been sent; if only some of the data was transmitted, the application needs to attempt delivery of the remaining data.

Use [`sendall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall) if you don't want to worry about checking if the data has been sent, as it'll continue to attempt to deliver the data until all the data has been delivered, or until an error occurs.

`Scanner` will tokenize the data based on a delimiter (which I believe by default is a whitespace). [`Scanner#next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) will only return data if the specified delimiter character was reached:

> A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.

Make sure you account for this while receiving the data (the data you send needs to specify the delimiter, the one for the scanner, somewhere). You can change the delimiter it via [`Scanner#useDelimiter(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter-java.lang.String-) or [`Scanner#useDelimiter(Pattern)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter-java.util.regex.Pattern-)

Comment: I tired both and it still did not print the output until the server side socket was closed

Comment: Ok I understood what you meant now. It did work finally. Thankyou